# Following Tim's recommendations has/have not led to good outcomes

Tags: gerunds, subject-verb-agreement

Which is correct?

> 1. Following Tim's recommendations in the past **has** not led to good outcomes.
> 2. Following Tim's recommendations in the past **have** not led to good outcomes.

Comment: *recommendations* are ***plural***, so they either ***have*** or ***haven't*** led to good outcomes. It's irrelevant that the recommendations came from Tim, who happens to be singular (so you could say *Tim **has** made some poor recommendations*, or that *Listening to Tim **has** not always been successful*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - However, it is not the recommendations that are the subject of the sentence, but the act of following them. The singular act of following recommendations is what has not led to good outcomes; therefore, *Following Tim's recommendations in the past **has** not led to good outcomes.*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - *Tim's recommendations **have** not led to good outcomes.*, however - the difference is that now the subject *is* Tim's recommendations, plural, rather than the singular act of following them.

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin: You're quite right - I didn't read the examples properly. But everything I said in the comment is true, and I did include a valid example with a gerund *(**listening**)* used as a singular subject, so I'll leave the comment there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence is an example of a [***gerund phrase***](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerundphrase.htm). Gerund phrases act in the sentence as nouns, and are treated as singular in number. Therefore, the gerund phrase *Following Tim's recommendations in the past* takes a singular verb, ***has***, giving *Following Tim's recommendations in the past **has** not led to good outcomes.*

If, however, the phrase had omitted the gerund, and was *Tim's recommendations in the past*, you would then have a plural noun, *recommendations*, and as such would take the plural verb, ***have***, giving *Tim's recommendations in the past **have** not led to good outcomes.*

Comment: Jeff Zetlin,  I believe you are correct. The gerund phrase is singular and must take the verb has. A similar example exists in Betty Azar's Chartbook: :Riding horses is fun.