# How Gerund affects subject verb agreement?

Tags: verbs, nouns, gerunds, subject-verb-agreement, present-participles

Eating sweets __________ (is/ are ) tough.

Contesting elections ______ ( is / are ) tough .

[ Which one is the subject Eating/ Contesting or sweets / elections ?]

According to Cambridge Grammar of English [ by Carter or Mccarthy ]
Gerund : A  word derived from a verb which ends in ing  is used as a noun.
Smoking is hazardous to health.

My Answer

Eating sweets is tough.

Contesting elections is tough.

But the nouns are in plural form ???????????

Comment: Hello. This looks like homework. Please show your attempt and explain why you think you are correct. Then we can agree or disagree and explain.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica: Please check now.

Comment: ***No**!* The *relevant* nouns (gerunds ***eating*** and ***contesting***) are NOT in the plural!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Following Tim's recommendations has/have not led to good outcomes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/137152/following-tims-recommendations-has-have-not-led-to-good-outcomes)

Comment: Non-finite clause subjects take singular agreement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Eating sweets is tough.
>
> Contesting elections is tough.

Your answers are correct (although eating sweets is not usually described as tough!)

Consider this sentence:

*Eating is tough if you have no teeth.*

It is clear that "eating" is the subject and that it is singular. If we add to this, e.g.

*Eating nuts is tough if you have no teeth.*

then the subject doesn't change - it is still "eating."

What about, "Nuts are tough"?

Well, it may be true that nuts are tough but that is a complete sentence. We can't easily add "Eating"

Eating: Nuts are tough (????????)

Does that help?

Comment: The point is that non-finite clause subjects take singular agreement.